# read from binary file and copy into array

Tags: c, arrays, fread, strcpy

its time over but anyway i want finish this problem. I want read binary file to buffer and later i want copy this buffer to array. I'm doing like that;

```
int i=0;
char *buffer;

buffer=(char *)malloc(filelen+1);  //filelen is length of binary file

while()
{
fread(buffer,100,1,filepointer);   //filepointer is input binary file pointer,i wanna read 100 byte
strcpy(tup[i],buffer); //tup[] is char array.i want copy buffer to in this array 
i++;
}
```

i got error at strcpy line you can not copy pointer to integer something like that.

thanx.

Comment: `buffer` isn't a proper terminated string, so you can't use `strcpy`. You could try `memcpy` instead, after checking the return value from fread (to see how many elements were actually read).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to write:

```
strcpy(&tup[i],buffer);
```

There are however a number of other issues.

1. How do you know that tup and buffer are null terminated. buffer is unlikely to be null terminate. You therefore should `memcpy` instead (with a known calculated length)
2. Are you sure that it is impossible to overwrite then end of `tup`?
3. since your temporary buffer is only reading 100 bytes at a time you do not need to allocate the full filesize of memory.

Comment: +1 Or use `tup+i` (which I prefer, but I'm a pointer-arithmetic guy).

Comment: I just used the form most similar to the OPs question.

Answer (score 1):

It must be:

```
strcpy(tup,buffer);
```

if tup is `char* tup`.

Also you can use `buffer[filelen]=0;` after you've used `malloc()` to allocate the memory for `buffer`, this will take care of the `'\0'` termination.

Comment: There is *no* reason to `memset()` and entire buffer with zeros only to immediately overwrite all but the last index with file content. A simple `buffer[filelen] = 0;` will suffice.